# Translate the value of twig variable

Tags: symfony, twig, translation, template-engine

Is it possible to translate the value of twig variables in a template with the 'trans' tag?

Say for instance I am passing a product to my template. This product has a definition with a trans tag e.g `{{ product.definition|trans }}`. This definition could either be in EN or DE or some other language. How could I translate the definition.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translating-database-content

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do is not a good way, It would look like this:

messages.en.yml

```
product:
    definition:
        some_value1: Some value 1
        some_value2: Some value 2
```

and in template, you would do something like this:

```
{% set definition_value = product.definition %}
{% set trans_definition = 'product.definition.' ~ definition_value %}
{{ trans_definition|trans }}
```

it'll work, if it finds the key. What if it cant find it?

That's why you should use [DoctrineBehaviors](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors) from KnpLabs, which handles all the dynamic translations for you..

Answer (score 1):

If `{{ product.definition }}` equals 'cellphone' the following should work.

message.language.yml:

```
'cellphone': This will work!
```

However if you want to map it with the 'product' key in your message file like this:

```
product:
    'cellphone': This also works
```

add the key to the twig template like so:

```
{{('product.'~product.definition)|trans }}
```